# symfony - web-profiler-bundle vs profiler-pack

Tags: symfony, composer-php

New to Symfony. I was wondering if anyone tell me the difference between these two - `web-profiler-bundle vs profiler-pack`? Which one should I install? Do I need both? Trying to find the difference between the two and not finding anything about them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Symfony Packs are, according to [a blog by Fabien Potencier](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-unpack-the-packs.html), "Composer metapackages that bundle several dependencies together". As you can see in the `composer.json` of `symfony/profiler-pack`, it simply depends on some packages (like the profiler bundle), and that's it. Packs provide no source code on their own.

"Which one should I install" is a good question, but it depends on your needs. If you don't know yet what you need, why install any of them?

Comment: Well, profiler is suppose to help with debugging in Symfony. Any help for me is good. I'll install the ```web-profiler-bundle``` and see what happens.

Comment: "Suppose to help" is fine - but do you know what you are looking for? Usually, debugging should be done using a debugger like XDebug within your IDE